# matchbox-terminal: Execute a script in the terminal from a .desktop file

Tags: bash, terminal, yocto

How can I write a .desktop file that will launch and execute a simple bash script in the matchbox-terminal?

My current helloworld.desktop looks like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Hello World terminal
Comment=Test app
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Exec=matchbox-terminal -e "bash -c /usr/bin/helloworld;$SHELL"
```

Launching helloworld.desktop, I would expect to see a new terminal displaying the stdout from the script.  Instead, launching the .desktop file opens a new matchbox-terminal but does not execute the script at all.

What is the proper matchbox-terminal command to make a new terminal and execute a script within it?

For the record, this is on an i.MX6 running core-image-sato.

Answer (score 3):

matchbox-terminal only accepts GTK+-related arguments, none of which involve running a separate command; it dumps `argc` and `argv` directly to `gtk_init()` and ignores them otherwise.

Comment: This is correct. Matchbox-terminal is very spartan... This particular feature would probably be welcome though: patches to mb-terminal are welcome on Yocto@yoctoproject.org.

Comment: In other words, this particular feature is not supported by matchbox-terminal?